# Email Templates Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to completely edit the code that gets used when this is called

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order
>   area="frontend"}}

I've tried editing

> app\design\frontend\Mgs\ethan\Magento_Bundle\templates\email

but no changes show up, i dont have an email folder in **magento_sales**.

I want to remove the SKU information from the email and change the table structure.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the SKU and change the table structure from this file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/itmes/order/default.phtml

One more file is responsible for table structure.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/itmes.phtml

Comment: that worked, i didnt have the vendor folder downloaded so when i did a search for certain bits of code from the email it was only found in the wrong location :(

All sorted now.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Happy coding :)